# JMeter NonGUIDriver error in non-GUI mode

Tags: jmeter

When I run JMeter test suite `jmeter -n -t test.jmx` in non-GUI mode on Ubuntu server, I get an error:

```
Error in NonGUIDriver com.thoughtworks.xstream.security.ForbiddenClassException: org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapper
```

What does this error mean? I installed JMeter on Ubuntu by command `sudo apt install jmeter`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most probably you're trying to open test plan created in more recent JMeter version with a very old JMeter from Ubuntu repositories.

- Looking at [jmeter package details](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=jmeter) it appears that Ubuntu has JMeter 2.13
- JMeter 2.13 was released in 2015
- Current stable version is [JMeter 5.5](https://lists.apache.org/thread/k575c2oqnr0pv52fckcg399o4nkqt8c6)

So remove the installation by `apt` and follow ["normal" JMeter installation procedure](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#lets_start):

1. Install Java version not lower than 8, i.e. `apt install openjdk-8-jdk`
2. Download JMeter 5.5, i.e. `wget https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-5.5.tgz`
3. Unpack it, i.e. `tar xf apache-jmeter-5.5.tgz`
4. Launch it `pushd apache-jmeter-5.5/bin/ && ./jmeter.sh`

The error should go away (at least this one)

More information: [JMeter Installation: How to Get Started](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-installation)